# Leaflet clearLayers is freezing browser

Tags: leaflet

I have a function that adds many circle markers to a layerGroup

```
const renderCatalogQuery = (catalog, catalogLayer) => {
    catalogLayer.clearLayers();
    catalogLayerControl.removeLayer(catalogLayer);
    catalogLayerControl.addOverlay(catalogLayer, catalog.name);
    for (let [name,lon,lat] of catalog.currentQuery) {
        let coordinates = L.latLng(lat,lon)
        let myMarker = L.circle(coordinates, {
            radius: catalog.markerSize,
            color: catalog.markerColor,
            weight: 1})
        myMarker.bindTooltip(`${name} (${catalog.name})`)                   
        myMarker.on('click', () => displayObjectInformation(catalog, name));
        myMarker.addTo(catalogLayer);
    }
}
```

`catalogLayerControl` is a control.layers , and `catalogLayer` is a layerGroup. The first time this run it's no problem. It will populate the layerGroup with circle markers and add the layer group to the layer control. The issue I am having is if the number of circle markers is quite large, the browser freezes up due to the `clearLayers()` method. It works fine for smaller markers. I can't figure out why adding the markers happens no problem, but removing them doesn't work. Is there a better approach I can take here?

Comment: What is "quite large"? Does the browser actually freeze, or is just taking a long time? Have you actually [checked what's the performance bottleneck](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance)?

Comment: It is slow enough that the browser pops up with the warning. The removeLayer method takes a long time to run. It's up to 200k circles on the map. They load reasonably fast, the map is reponsive with them on. But as soon as I try to remove them it takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing clear layers is not the culprit, but adding circles one by one while the Layer Group is still on map is more likely to give performance issue.

Try removing the Layer Group from the map before your loop, then add it back once you are done, so that the heavy computation happens only once.

```js
const renderCatalogQuery = (catalog, catalogLayer) => {
    catalogLayer.remove(); // First remove the Layer Group from map
    catalogLayer.clearLayers();
    for (let [name,lon,lat] of catalog.currentQuery) {
        // ...
        myMarker.addTo(catalogLayer);
    }
    catalogLayer.addTo(map); // Finally re-add to map
}
```

Comment: Hi, this still does not seem to be working for me. The Layer Group instantly clears from the map. But calling clearLayers hangs the browser regardless. Is there maybe a workaround where I can somehow just literally delete everything to do with the old layerGroup and create a new one?